# How to make a relationship diagram between attributes in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 8 and need some help...

I have 3 database tables like below:

```
**Entities table**
Entity_id  Entity_name
  1         first_entity
  2         second_entity....and so on
```

```
**Attributes table**
attribute_id  attribute_name
  1           first_attr
  2           second_attr....and so on
```

```
**Enitity_attribute Mapping**   
  id          Entity_id                      attribute_id               
  1           1                                2
  2           1                                3
  3           1                                4
  4           2                                5
  5           2                                6
  6           2                                7 and so on...
```

As you can see one entity has multiple attributes. In the front end, I am listing down all the entities in the left side and clicking on any entity will show related attribute

[image]

one more table data coming from api:

```
**Attributes relations**
 id           entity_id        attribute_id   entity_foreign_key_id  attributed_foreign_key_id
  1           1                 2                  3                     5
  2           1                 3                  4                     7
```

In above table I am getting the relation between the attributes of different entities. I want draw image or line between the attributes as shown in below picture.[image]

I am calling this method when any entity is clicked:

```
showAttributes(entityId) {
    this.entandApi.getAttributes_by_entity(entityId).subscribe((data: any) => {
      let getAttributeResp = data;
    })
  }
```

I have tried below code using jquery:

```
var line = $('#line');
var div1 = $('#first-div');
var div2 = $('#second-div');

var x1 = div1.offset().left + (div1.width());
var y1 = div1.offset().top + (div1.height()/2);
var x2 = div2.offset().left;
var y2 = div2.offset().top+ (div1.height()/2);

line.attr('x1',x1).attr('y1',y1).attr('x2',x2).attr('y2',y2);
```

But not sure how to achieve this in Angular 8.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: using `ViewChild()` you can apply direct DOM manipulations on your elements. a safer approach would be injecting [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) and using that instead.

Comment: Apart from BillingCycle you want to match Follow_Up_CD & Customer_Accout_Seq etc?

Comment: Yes, attributes present in **Attributes relation** table will be joined

Answer (score 1):

I have used this library https://anseki.github.io/leader-line/ and it is working as expected. Below is the code I used

```
<div id="start">start</div>
<div id="end">end</div>

new LeaderLine(
  document.getElementById('start'),
  document.getElementById('end')
);
```